# Корректен ли этот код для 64-битных систем?

Tags: c#, x86-64, unsafe

Этот код заполняет массив от 0 до 1000000 используя указатели через небезопасный контекст. Вопрос заключается в том: корректен ли этот код для 64-битных систем? Если нет, то как его нужно переписать?
Есть сомнение, что указатель будет указывать за пределы 32-битной области, а так как используется int произойдёт ошибка. Не понимаю как сделать указатель типа long.

```
private const int count = 1000000;
private readonly int[] arr = new int[count];

public void Test()
{
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (int* ptr = arr)    
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                *(ptr + i) = i;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Причем здесь указатель типа int? Указатель тупо хранит адрес на область в памяти, он не хранит ваши данные, какими они не были бы, 32-х или 64-х битными и т.д.

Comment: Так вопрос как раз об этом. В 64-битной системе адрес памяти может превысить 32-битную область. И следуя из этого я пытаюсь понять, будет ли работать этот код без сбоев.

Comment: будет работать, т.к. `int` это данные, которые хранятся по указателю и размер указателя не зависит от того `int` это или `long`, runtime сам будет использовать правильные размеры адреса

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо за ответ.